# Laravel user input form to query database

Tags: laravel, userform

been trying to create a laravel form with several fields that the user can enter text/number into a field and it takes the field with data and performs a database query. Now the form works with just one field but when i add more fields it only returns data for the final query, not for the other two.

perfumes controller

```
class perfumescontroller extends Controller
{
  public function index()
 {
   $pstoreNum = request('pstoreNum');


   $result = perfumes::where('StoreNumber','=',$pstoreNum)
        ->get();

    return view('perfumes',compact('result'));


   }

   public function perfWeekSearch()
    {
   $weekNum = request('perfWeekNum');


   $result = perfumes::where('WeekNumber','=',$weekNum)
        ->get();

    return view('perfumes',compact('result'));


    }


    }
```

Route::get('/perfumes', 'perfumescontroller@index');
Route::get('/perfumes', 'perfumescontroller@perfWeekSearch');

Blade:

```
<form action="perfumes" method="get">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="perfWeekNum"                     placeholder="Type in Store Number"> 
                  <span class="input-group-btn"> 
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>
                  </span>
              </div>
          </form>
```

Do i need to use some sort of check if not null method? or is there an easier way??

Thanks

Comment: You should probably show us the code that doesn't work instead of showing the version with the single input field

Answer (score 0):

**I think this would be work below is your perfumes controller**

```
  class perfumescontroller extends Controller
  {
     public function index()
     {
       $data = $request->all();

       if(!empty($data['pstoreNum'])){
       $pstoreNum = $data['pstoreNum'];


        $result = DB::table('perfumes')->where('StoreNumber','=',$pstoreNum)
                  ->get();

      return view('perfumes',compact('result'));
      } else if(!empty($data['perfWeekNum'])){
          $weekNum = $data['perfWeekNum'];


          $result = DB::table('perfumes')->where('WeekNumber','=',$weekNum)
                 ->get();

           return view('perfumes',compact('result'));
       }

      }



 }
```

**and you use any with route like below:**

```
   Route::any('/perfumes', 'perfumescontroller@index');
```

Comment: It returns an error: Undefined variable request on line 28 which is the following line:

Comment: $data = $request->all();

Comment: hello would you answer me that is whats framework you use cakephp, laravel

Comment: you follow this url https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests may be its syntex error